# How do I allow the user to choose which def function they want to use... by using a main function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I think I am supposed to use `__name__='__main__'`

```
def rec(a,b):
    if b == 0:
        return a
    else:
        return rec(b,a%b)

a = int(input("please enter the 1st number_"))
b = int(input("please enter the 2nd number_"))

ans=rec(a,b)
print("The greatest common divisor is:",ans)

#calculating gcd using iteration:
def iter(a, b):
   while(b):
       a, b = b, a % b

   return a

a = int(input("please enter the 1st number_"))
b = int(input("please enter the 2nd number_"))
ans=iter(a,b)
print("gcd is",ans)
```

Comment: Please explain clearly what output you want, what you have tried and why it doesn't work. I'm guessing you want to give the user a choice of which if these two functions to run?

Comment: yes, this is how it is supposed to look like:

Comment: Select the GCD function to use:
1. Recursive 2. Iterative
Please select a function: 1
Please enter the first number: 48 Please enter the second number: 18
The greatest common denominator is 6

Comment: You don't need a `main` function. You can just ask them for their choice, and use `if` statements to call the appropriate function.

Comment: I know, it's just my professor specified that I need to use a main function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a `main()` function that prompts for the choice and uses an `if` statement.

```
def rec(a,b):
    if b == 0:
        return a
    else:
        return rec(b,a%b)

def iter(a, b):
   while(b):
       a, b = b, a % b

   return a

def main():
    while True:
        choice = int(input("Select the GCD function to use: 1. Recursive 2. Iterative:"))
        if choice == 1 or choice == 2:
            break
        print("Please enter 1 or 2")

    a = int(input("please enter the 1st number_"))
    b = int(input("please enter the 2nd number_"))

    if choice == 1:
        ans = rec(a, b)
    elif choice == 2:
        ans = iter(a, b)

    print("The greatest common divisor is:",ans)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```